# How should I handle RESTful authentication while using JWT tokens?

Tags: node.js, rest, express, jwt, restful-authentication

I have read many articles and viewed many videos but there are a lot of contradictions. I try to avoid any external libraries and build the system from scratch, I have read about oAuth 2 but it is more confusing.

This is the flow that I think is ok untill now:

1. User fills a form using email and password and submits it.
2. Server verifies the password if it matches and responds back with a httponly cookie with a signed jwt token that expires in like 10
   minutes. (I know I have to protect it against csrf attacks)
3. User gets logged in and every new request he is making to the server he will send the cookie in the header automatically and the
   server will verify the token.

Everything is fine but I have encountered some issues and have some questions:

I want the user to stay logged in even after opening a new session so there is no need to login after the token expired or when he closes the browser.

What should happen if the access token expired?

There should be a refresh token attached to the user in database that gets added when the user logs in with an expiration of ex 7 days, then the server will respond with a cookie containing that refresh token?

On the new request while access token is expired,the user will send the refresh cookie to the server, if it matches the user database refresh token,server will respond with a separate cookie that will renew the access token?

If there is a refresh token where should you store it and what format? (cookie,database or where?)

Should I keep the user logged in based on this refresh token cookie?If is it httponly I can't read it and set the state that user is logged in. How should I do it?

I heard about that revoking the jwt token is problematic. How would you fix it?

How would you do this whole thing?Please explain the workflow, I try to avoid localstorage,as I read everywhere that is not safe for sensitive data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented and deployed to production systems that do exactly the kinds of things that you are asking about here so I think that I am qualified to provide you with some guidance to solve your particular issues and answer your questions. The flow that you have listed above in the numbered list is definitely the correct path so far. I do understand your confusion going forward from there because there are many different options for how to approach this problem.

In addition to providing a login route that returns a new JWT to the client when the user submits a login form to the server, I would recommend also implementing a token refresh route that accepts a still valid JWT that was received from the initial login process and returns a new JWT with an updated expiration time. The logic for this new token refresh route should first verify that the provided JWT is still valid by matching it with a user in the database. Then, it should generate a new token using the same JWT generation logic as the login route logic. Then, the application should overwrite the access token data in the database for the user replacing the old access token with the newly generated access token. It is not necessary to keep an old access token in the database once it is no longer valid, which is why I suggest simply overwriting it with a new one. Once all of that is finished and successful, you can return the new JWT to the client and then the client should now use that new JWT when making any additional authenticated calls to the server to maintain an authenticated interaction with the server. This logic flow would keep the user logged in, because the client would have a valid JWT before calling the refresh logic and it would have a valid JWT after calling the refresh logic. The user should only be recognized as not logged in and not authenticated if they are no longer able to provide a valid access token that is associated with a user in the database.

As far as cookies go, whichever method that you use for maintaining the cookies on your client should be used for setting the refreshed access token as it is for setting the initial access token that you receive on login. If the server finds that an access token is no longer valid at some point in the future, if for example your client is not used after login until some time after the access token has expired, then the client should recognize a server response indicating that this is the case and present the user with the login flow on the client again so that a new access token can be acquired and stored in a cookie on the client.

I would not worry about revoking JWTs and instead just let them expire if they do and initiate a new login flow if it is found that a JWT has expired. Also, instead of using local storage I would suggest using session storage to store your JWT so that you have it for the duration of your user's session on the website and it is removed as soon as the browser has been closed. This will prevent the JWT from persisting beyond the session and should assuage your fears about saving sensitive data in the session storage. Also, when generating your JWT, you should also make a point of not storing any sensitive data in it because JWTs are easily reverse-engineered. This can also prevent any sort of sensitive data from being exposed on the client.

EDIT:

The key thing to remember when developing your server API is that you should have two different classes of endpoints. One set should be unauthenticated and one set should be authenticated.

The authenticated set of endpoints would not require an access token to be included in the request. An example of this class of endpoint would be your login endpoint, which does not require an access token because it actually generates an access token for you to use later on. Any other endpoint that does not expose sensitive or important information could be included in this class of endpoints.

The unauthenticated set of endpoints would require an access token to be included in the request, and if no access token or an invalid access token is detected the endpoint would respond with a [401 HTTP response code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401) (indicating an unauthorized request). An example of this class of endpoint would be an endpoint that allows a user to update their personal information. Obviously, a user cannot update their own information if they cannot provide credentials to prove that they are the user whose information they are attempting to update. If the client receives a response with a 401 response code, that would be the signal that the client would need in order to tell the user to re-login so that a new valid access token can be retrieved. This possibility can be avoided on the client if the client is programmed to periodically check the expiration of the JWT that is currently being held on the client and initiate an access token refresh, but obviously you should still have logic in place to detect and respond to a 401 response code so that the client user flow is managed properly.

Comment: Thank you a for the effort, it really helped me a lot, I have made a summary and I will re-read everything you said more times to make sure I don't miss anything, please tell me if I'm wrong somewhere. I know I miss the details in the summary but hope the this is the flow.

Comment: on user login
-a access token is stored in database attached to hes account

token refresh route
-on every new user request,the route accepts a still valid access jwt token
-verifies if its matching with a user in the database
-should generate a new token using the same logic on login route and returns a the token with updated expiration
-server should overwrite the access token data in the database for the user, replacing the old one

-if token expired server will tell the browser to logout and ask the user to login again
-use session storage for storing jwt tokens

Comment: Your summarized flow looks good and you have covered all of the major points. After reading your comments I wanted to make sure that I mentioned one other thing about your server API design. Please see my edit above for those details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, now everything is clear. Got one more short and last question: in case if there are roles (example: admins) is there need for a second layer of security? like a second layer system of tokens? or adding roles key in the JWT and verify will do the job?Or maybe it needs a complete different system.

Comment: As with the previous questions you asked, there are different ways to implement this part of a system depending on your application needs. If you want the database to manage permissions so that you do not need to worry about it in your application logic, you can use role-based security in the database. Or if you want more control in your application, you can define a role set in your application code and check for roles in your application logic on API call. I have done both, but I would recommend for you starting out to add a "roles" field in your JWT that you can check during each API call.